# Open a pop-up/modal window after add/edit node to share

Tags: nodes

I'm using [Social Share](http://drupal.org/project/social-share) to generate share links on my nodes but I want the user to be prompted to share after adding and/or editing a node. Is there any possibility of creating a pop-up/modal window that contains those links after the add/edit window has been submitted?

Answer (score 1):

without coding, you could setup a message in rules and show it with [Better Messages](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) or similar (there is a [link](http://groups.drupal.org/node/51088) to a wiki on the project page) or you could acheive the popup with some coding and the hidden gems of [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) (see the examples in ctools)